# Tailwind overscroll y not working properly

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I'm building a laravel/tailwind dashboard but I'm now facing an issue with the overflow of an element.

The design I want to achieve is the follwing :
[image: design]

And what i achieved until now is the following:
[image]

With this code structure :

```
<body>
    <div id="app" class="max-h-screen flex flex-col">
    <nav class="bg-white border-gray-200 flex flex-wrap h-fit justify-between shadow items-center p-0 m-0">
        
    </nav>

    <div class="flex max-h-full grid grid-cols-8">
        <aside class="h-full flex col-span-1" aria-label="Sidebar"  id="sidebar">
            
        </aside>  
        <div class="w-full bg-gray-100 p-5 col-span-7 flex-1 m-0">
            
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

## The issue

I would like to have only the body as scrollable ans keep the sidebar and the navbar in the same fixed position they are at any time.

Unfortunately, when i add the `overflow-y-auto` class to the div where the body is, the overflow is applied to the whole window breaking the design.

Do you have any suggestion on how i can make only the body scrollable with the above code base?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Method 1: using `fixed` classes

Idea :  make the `nav` and `aside` elements `fixed`

```html
<body>
    <div id="app" class="h-screen flex flex-col">
        <nav class="bg-white border-gray-200 flex flex-wrap h-fit justify-between shadow items-center p-0 m-0 w-full fixed top-0 left-0 z-10">
        
        </nav>
        <aside class="h-screen fixed top-0 left-0 w-60 flex col-span-1" aria-label="Sidebar"  id="sidebar">
            
        </aside>  
        <div class="w-4/5 ml-auto bg-gray-100 p-5 col-span-7 flex-1 overflow-y">
            
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
```

## Method 2: using `sticky` class

```html
<body>
    <div id="app" class="max-h-screen flex flex-col">
        <nav class="bg-white border-gray-200 flex flex-wrap h-fit justify-between shadow items-center p-0 m-0 w-full fixed top-0 left-0 z-10">
            
        </nav>
    
        <div class="flex max-h-full grid grid-cols-8 relative h-screen overflow-hidden">
            <aside class="h-screen flex col-span-1 sticky top-0" aria-label="Sidebar"  id="sidebar">
                
            </aside>  
            <div class="w-full overflow-auto bg-gray-100 p-5 col-span-7 flex-1 m-0">
                
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

You might have to experiment with the `div` widths as I am just roughly eyeballing the values with `w-4/5` and `w-60` classes.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Yes, this was originally in my mind, but i noticed that when the body has some overflow it makes also the sidebar stretching all togheter. While, i want only the body to be stretched.

Comment: The fixed approach will work for you then. Make both the nav and aside elements fixed and make the parent element's overflow-hidden. The child body div will have overflow-y class.

Comment: The issue with fixed is that the element doesn't keep the space occupied breaking the layout. And also that with fixed top-0 the sidebar will be fixed at the top left corner of the screen while i need it to be fix at thebottom left corner of the nav...Also the overflow hidden doesn't solve the problem with the nav as the nav has some links at the bottom...